# How to create file with open function in Python?

Tags: python, linux, file

In Linux environment, I want to create a file and write text into it:

```
HTMLFILE: "$MYUSER/OUTPUT/myfolder/mytext.html"
f = open(HTMLFILE, 'w')

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "$MYUSER/OUTPUT/myfolder/mytext.html"
```

I have read/write permission do "$MYUSER/OUTPUT/myfolder/" directories.

Why do I get this error? Why doesn't it create mytext.html file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`os.path.expandvars()` can help:

```
f = open(os.path.expandvars(HTMLFILE), 'w')
```

`open` only deals with actual file names.  `expandvars` can expand environment variables in strings.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways. Using os.environ() to get variable value

```
HTML_PATH = "/OUTPUT/myfolder/mytext.html"
f = open(os.environ('MYUSER') + HTMLFILE, 'w')
```

and using os.path.expandvars():

```
HTMLFILE = "$MYUSER/OUTPUT/myfolder/mytext.html"
f = open(os.path.expandvars(HTMLFILE), 'w')
```

Answer (score 3):

`$MYUSER` refers to a shell variable. Python does not resolve those. Use the `os` package to get the users home directory  through `os.getenv('MYUSER')`